# Python error importing already install module

Tags: python, module

I'm having an error with Python successfully installing a module but not being to load it.

Currently I'm using Python 3.5.1, Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit) in a Juptyer notebook on Windows 7.

I ran `pip install quandl` which completed successfully. If I run it again I get

```
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): quandl in
> c:\users\crushee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Additionally the quandl module is listed when I run `pip freeze`

When I'm in the notebook and run `sys.path` it also returns that same installation directory. I've also added this directory to PYTHONPATH system variable in Windows

```
> ['',  'C:\\Users\\crushee\\Anaconda3\\Lib', 
> 'c:\\users\\crushee\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg',
> 'C:\\Users\\crushee\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\
```

However when I try `import quandl` it returns an error of

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ab7fa5ad38a5> in <module>()
----> 1 import quandl

ImportError: No module named 'quandl'
```

Lastly here's the output if I try to import it in verbose mode

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in > _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked   ImportError: No module name 'quandl'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import Quandl
```

You might face other import errors for other packages (like I faced import error for `pandas`. So, install `pandas`). It is installed as `Quandl` in `/usr/local/lib/<python>/dist-packages`.

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help